# Two HTML Issues: Width 100% not working and Divs not separating from each other

Tags: html, width

First of all, in the portfolio section where the images are shown, the css property

```
width: 100%
```

is not working.

Second, I have two DIVs that are, for some reason, stuck together.

How would I fix these?

The fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/WjP9H/

CLARIFICATION: The two divs that are stuck together are the "images" and the "about" divs. As you can see, the background color for the "about" div is also stuck into the "images" div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any content in the DIVs?  Sometimes if there is not any content in the DIVs, it will collapse even when you set the width to 100%.

As for DIVs being stuck together, have you tried adding a margin to the DIVs?

```
<div style="margin: 5px">Some content here.</div>
<div style="margin: 5px">Other content here.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First problem: Add margin:0 to your body.
Second problem: Which divs do you mean?

Comment: The two divs that are stuck together are the "images" and the "about" divs. As you can see, the background color for the "about" div is also stuck into the "images" div.

Comment: You need to clear the floated div.box. Add <br style="clear:both;" /> after the last <div class="box"></div> in #container and your content is separated.